# Why NSLog outputs garbles when logging Chinese characters?

Tags: objective-c

NSLog displays unknown garble with the following code:

```
NSString *sampleStr = @"你好";
NSLog(sampleStr);
```

But it outputs:

[image]

As I send the above characters to backend, backend shows

```
?????
```

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

What the problem specifically? `NSLog`ging or the backend one?

If the former, first of all, you should use string formatting to output strings instead of passing the `NSString` object directly. This must give you desired output:

```
NSLog(@"%@", sampleStr);
```

Though, I tried your code without changes in Xcode 13.1 and it gave me the desired output nevertheless. So, probably the problem is somewhere else, not in your `NSLog`:

```
NSString *sampleStr = @"你好";

// "Format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)"
NSLog(sampleStr); // 你好

NSLog(@"%@", sampleStr); // 你好
```

If you mean backend as your problem, it depends on how you "send" it to backend (in a body as data, as an HTTP parameter as text, with/without escaping, etc.) and whether your backend code supports the input you provide. To answer that more precisely we should have more information.